# A macro for long and short function names in C++

Tags: c++, macros, alias, naming

I am currently working on a general-purpose C++ library.
Well, I like using real-word function names and actually my project has a consistent function naming system. The functions (or methods) start with a *verb* if they do not return bool (in this case they start with is_)
The problem is this can be somewhat problematic for some programmers. Consider this function:

```
#include "something.h"
int calculate_geometric_mean(int* values)
{
//insert code here
}
```

I think such functions seem to be formal, so I name my functions so.
However I designed a simple Macro system for the user to switch function names.

```
#define SHORT_NAMES
#include "something.h"
#ifdef SHORT_NAMES
int calc_geometric_mean(int* values)
#else
int calculate_geometric_mean(int* values)
#endif
{
//some code
}
```

Is this wiser than using alias (since each alias of function will be allocated in the memory), or is this solution a pure evil?

Comment: There's nothing inherently evil about it, but I don't think removing five letters from the function name adds enough value to overcome the disadvantage of having two separate API's.

Comment: `"is"` is a verb, actually.

Comment: I love how you're cautious about whether what you write is evil. I wish there were more people like you.

Comment: I would favour removing all the vowels. I don't like code with vowels in it.

Comment: @juanchopanza, On the contrary. It should have only vowels.

Comment: How about keep only the long names in your library. That will seriously cleanup your code. Then, if you want to ofer a vowels-free symbol (taking @chris or @juanchopanza suggestion), you can also provide macros: `#define clclt_gmtrc_mn calculate_geometric_mean`, (or a short inline, or, if your library is a DLL - you can export aliases).

Comment: That's a good idea Uri, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I don't think this dual-naming system adds a lot of value. It does, however, has the potential for causing a lot of confusion (to put it mildly).

In any case, if you are convinced is a great idea, I would implement it through inline functions rather than macros.

```
// something.h

int calculate_geometric_mean(int* values); // defined in the .cpp file

inline int calc_geo_mean(int* values) {
   return calculate_geometric_mean(values);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What symbols will be exported to the object file/library? What if you attempt to use the other version? Will you distribute two binaries with their own symbols?

So - no, bad idea.

Comment: Yes you are correct for static libraries and dlls; but I thought to use this system for functions that are defined only in the header files. So no symbols are required to work with those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the purpose behind a naming system is to aid the readability and understanding of the code.

Now, you effectively have 2 systems, each of which has a rationale. You're already forcing the reader/maintainer to keep two approaches to naming in mind, which dilutes the end goal of readability. Never mind the ugly #defines that end up polluting your code base.

I'd say choose one system and stick to it, because consistency is the key. I wouldn't say this solution is pure evil per se - I would say that this is not a solution to begin with.